# Does Kivy have laserjet printer support?

Tags: python, kivy

Is there a way to print a `Page/Widget/Label` in Kivy? (or some other way in python).

Unfortunately, I don't know how to ask the question correctly since I am new to software development.

I want to build a price tracking app for my business in which i will have to print some stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly, no, but the printing part isn't really Kivy's responsibility - probably you can find another Python module to handle this.

In terms of what is printed, you can export an image of any part of the Kivy gui and print that.